# Can I access a pod from external network even the sidecar container is crashBackLoop

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have a Kubernetes pod with 2 containers, and expose a service with TCP protocol for this pod to `kubernetes/ingress-nginx`. If the sidecar container is in a bad state, can I still access the default container? Currently I get timeout when I curl it.

Comment: How do you want to access the other container? console or network? If you want to access the other container via console, you can run ```kubectl exec -ti <podname> -c <container name> sh``` (if you have a bash built in your container). If you want to access it via network, it really depends on what's the function of the sidecar container. It if is a traffic intercepter(proxy,reverse proxy), you may not be able to access the container from the exposed port. However, you can try to access the other container via it's original port. Hope that helps.

Comment: @HangDu I updated the title, I wanna expose the pod to external network with an ingress-nginx controller. However once the sidecar (nothing related to the network) crashes, the nginx returns 502. I also try to expose a LoadBalancer for this deployment, the LoadBalancer gets timeout as well in this situation. I think may I add some annotations for the service or deployment to make the network unblocked.

Comment: Did you try `kubectl port-forward` to the pod?

Comment: @weibeld Yes, it is ok to access the port in the pod, I can also curl it in another pod with pod internal IP. However, if I try to curl the ClusterIP which maps to the pod cannot work.

Comment: How many ports does the pod expose? Which port do you use for `port-forward`? And what is the target port of the ClusterIP service?